# Context Error while using Django-tables2 in my Project

Tags: django, python-3.7, django-tables2

I am attempting to implement Django-tables2 into my project. I am able to render the object_list, but when I alter the template to render_table table, it fails.

I am seeing this error upon rending my template:

`Exception Type:    AttributeError
Exception Value:    context`

Here are my following files

**Views.py**

```
class DeviceTable_New(SingleTableView):
    table_class = DeviceTable
    template_name = "device_app/device_list.html"
    paginator_class = LazyPaginator
```

**Tables.py**

```
class DeviceTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        template_name = "device_app/device_list.html"
        fields = ("id", "type", "processed","donated_to_recipient")
```

**urls.py**

```
path('device_list/',views.DeviceTable_New.as_view(),name='device_list'),
```

**Template** (Not the full page. There is proprietary information on this page.)

```
       <div class='col-md-8'>
          <div class="jumbotron">
              <h1>Devices</h1>
              <hr>
              <p><a class='button' href="{% url 'device_app:device_create'%}">Create Device</a</p>

              {% render_table table %}
          </div>
        </div>
```

EDIT: If I alter small portions of code (multiple variations have been attempted) I end up seeing this:
 `Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.`

EDIT 2: I have created an [issue ticket](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/issues/706) on the Django-tables2 repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was related to the tables.py. The first iteration of this file utilized this line:

```
template_name = "device_app/device_list.html"
```

`template_name` is not related to the template you are rendering. It is related to the django_tables2 existing templates for table rendering.

Replacing the previously shown line with this:

```
template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
```

Eliminated my issue.

`template_name` can be altered to reflect custom formatting, but for this question it was only essential to understand the error I was facing.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's very little to go on but with what I can see, it seems the error may have been raised because you tried to retrieve an attribute `context` from an object (eg data.context) where it does not exist. A picture or stack trace of the error could help clear things up

Comment: The stack trace is over 3000 lines. I would believe pasting it here would not be helpful. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Alright then did you retrieve an attribute context along the course of execution example `data.context`?

Comment: Not sure I am following what you are asking, but here is what is returned for the context value in the trace: `context 
[{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}, {'table': <device_app.tables.DeviceTable object at 0x1222ff748>}]`

Comment: Okay so what does the first line of the error page say?

Comment: `/python/django_tables2_repo/django-tables2/django_tables2/templatetags/django_tables2.py in render
            return template.render(context={"table": table}, request=request) …

context 
[{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}, {'table': <device_app.tables.DeviceTable object at 0x122af37b8>}]
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/device/device_list/'>
self 
<django_tables2.templatetags.django_tables2.RenderTableNode object at 0x12263cb38>
table 
<device_app.tables.DeviceTable object at 0x122af37b8>
template 
<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x12263cda0>`